# Configuring unit testing within an Ionic3 application

Tags: ionic3, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I'm implementing unit tests within an ionic3 project based on the following sample project: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-unit-testing-example.

It works fine but I have some issues:

- I can see compilation errors (for jasmine) whereas these ones don't prevent from running tests

  ```
  karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js
  webpack: Compiled successfully.
  webpack: Compiling...

  17 03 2018 15:53:18.403:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/

  ERROR in ./src/pages/test/test.spec.ts
  [tsl] ERROR in /home/app-path/src/pages/test/test.spec.ts(11,1)
  TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.

  ERROR in ./src/pages/test/test.spec.ts
  [tsl] ERROR in /home/app-path/src/pages/test/test.spec.ts(17,3)
  TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.

  ERROR in ./src/pages/test/test.spec.ts
  [tsl] ERROR in /home/app-path/src/pages/test/test.spec.ts(40,39)
  TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

  ERROR in ./src/pages/test/test.spec.ts
  [tsl] ERROR in /home/app-path/src/pages/test/test.spec.ts(42,3)
  TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.

  ...

  webpack: Failed to compile.
  17 03 2018 15:53:18.422:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
  17 03 2018 15:53:18.422:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
  17 03 2018 15:53:18.748:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
  17 03 2018 15:53:20.153:INFO [Chrome 57.0.2987 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket py7H3olXgBzYBE2DAAAA with id 24040166
  Chrome 57.0.2987 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 8 of 8 SUCCESS (2.716 secs / 0 secs)
  ```
- I can't display results in the browser launched by karma even if I have the `kjhtml` reporter configured. See https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-unit-testing-example/blob/master/test-config/karma.conf.js#L52. Note I added the `progress` reporter and it works fine:

  ```
  reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
  ```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For the first: set ts-loader to 3.5.0